# Stata ' rolling ' command: saving variables instead of .dta files

Tags: stata

I am using the rolling command in a foreach loop:

```
use "MyFile.dta"
tsset time, monthly

foreach i of varlist var1 var2 {
rolling _b, window(12) saving(beta_`i'): reg `i' DependentVariable
}
```

Now, this code saves a different file for each rolling regression. What I would really like is to save each vector of betas obtained from the rolling estimation as a variable.
The final result I would like to obtain is a dataset with a time variable and a "beta_var#" variable for each rolling:

```
 time    | beta_var1 | beta_var2 
_________|___________|__________
 1990m1  |    ##     |  ##
 1990m2  |    ##     |  ##
 ...     |    ##     |  ##
 200m12  |    ##     |  ##
 1990m1  |    ##     |  ##
```

(PS: secondary question: is there a shortcut to indicate a varlist = to all the variables in the dataset?)

Comment: You can refer to all variables using `_all` or `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misread your post and my initial answer does not give what you ask for. Here's one way. Not elegant nor very efficient but it works (just change directory names):

```
clear all 
set more off

* Do not mix with previous trials
capture erase "/home/roberto/results.dta"

* Load data
sysuse sp500
tsset date

* Set fixed independent variable
local var open

foreach depvar of varlist high low close volume {

    rolling _b, window(30) saving(temp, replace): regress `depvar' `var'
    use "/home/roberto/temp.dta", clear
    rename (_b_`var' _b_cons) (b_`depvar' b_cons_`depvar')

    capture noisily merge 1:1 start end using "/home/roberto/results.dta", assert(match)
    capture noisily drop _merge
    save "/home/roberto/results.dta", replace

    sysuse sp500, clear
    tsset date
}

* Delete auxiliary file
capture erase "/home/roberto/temp.dta"

* Check results
use "/home/roberto/results.dta"
browse
```

Maybe other solutions can be proposed using `postfile` or concatenating vectors of results and converting to a dataset using `svmat`. I'm not sure.

**Original answer**

Use the `saving()` option with `replace` and provide only one file name (drop the macro suffix) :

```
clear all
set more off

webuse lutkepohl2
tsset qtr
rolling _b, window(30) saving(results, every(5) replace): regress dln_inv dln_inc dln_consump
```

Comment: @Giuseppe, I've edited my answer. The original one does not give what you asked for.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just have 1 problem. Your code as it is works perfectly, but when I go to my dataset I get a problem: `rename (_b_`var' _b_cons) (b_`depvar' b_cons_`depvar')` gives me : _oldnames and newnames do not match
    You specified 1 pattern or name for oldname and 2 patterns or names for     newnames_. The prbolem disappears removing `depvar' from the constant name,  but then it overwrites the constants.

Comment: @Giuseppe, the number of old_names has to match the number of new_names when using `rename`. I'd check what `rename` is being fed right before the command is called. You can use `display` for this. The error you cite says you are giving one old_name and two new_names. Check your code to verify there is a blank space between the two old_names. Check also at what step in the loop the error comes up. Is it in the first loop, an intermediate loop? This will help you determine if you're having a problem with a specific variable name.

Comment: You can post a link (using some cloud service) to a simplified version of your database (e.g. first 15 observations for all variables) if you need further help.